# Android: pass a JSONobject between Fragments

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I'm working on a little Weather app which uses a ListFragment to show the weather for each day and a detail fragment with more information.  I'm trying to get each detail fragment to show the corresponding weather for each listview day.  Here are some snippets of code:

Parts of the ListFragment:

```
    public class WeatherListFragment extends ListFragment implements LocationListener{

        private final String initialURL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/8fc2b0556e166fa4670d4014d318152a/";
        Weather[] myWeatherArray = {};
        WeatherAdapter weatherAdapter;
        LocationManager mLocationManager;
        String currentLoc;
        JSONObject day;

        OnWeatherSelectedListener mCallback;

        // The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
        public interface OnWeatherSelectedListener {
            /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
            public void onWeatherSelected(int position, String data);
        }



@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //call back to the parent activity with the selected item

        mCallback.onWeatherSelected(position, data);
        l.setItemChecked(position, true);


    }


 try {
                    JSONObject daily = response.getJSONObject("daily");
                    JSONArray data = daily.getJSONArray("data");
                    myWeatherArray = new Weather[data.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < myWeatherArray.length; i++) {
                        day = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        Weather myWeatherObject = new Weather();
                        myWeatherObject.setmDate(day.getInt("time"));
                        myWeatherObject.setmTempMin(day.getInt("temperatureMin"));
                        myWeatherObject.setmTempMax(day.getInt("temperatureMax"));
                        myWeatherObject.setIcon(day.getString("icon"));
                        myWeatherArray[i] = myWeatherObject;

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

The main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements WeatherListFragment.OnWeatherSelectedListener {

 @Override
    public void onWeatherSelected(int position, String data) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment


        WeatherDetailFragment weatherDetailFragment = (WeatherDetailFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.weather_detail_fragment);

        //One pane layout
        if(weatherDetailFragment == null) {
            WeatherDetailFragment onePaneFragment = new WeatherDetailFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(WeatherDetailFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);

            onePaneFragment.setArguments(args);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, onePaneFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

The detail fragment:

```
public class WeatherDetailFragment extends Fragment {



    final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";

    int mCurrentPosition = -1;
.
.
.
public void updateWeatherView(int position, String data) {

        View v = getView();
        TextView day = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView);
        TextView date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        TextView tempMin = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tempMinTextView);
        TextView tempMinF = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tempMinFTextView);
        TextView tempMax = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tempMaxTextView);
        TextView tempMaxF = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tempMaxFTextView);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


        mCurrentPosition = position;
    }
.
.
}
```

Comment: use interface as a call back. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Sorry I know this.  I'm using a callback to pass the listview position from the listfragment, to the Activity, then back down to the detail fragment.  I'm not sure how to convert the JSONobject for each day to a String the pass it back.

Comment: How about bind to HashMap object class and send it to other fragment !

Answer (score 16):

Passing `JSONObject` can be easier if you use the `Bundle` object. Convert the `JSONObject` to a `String` by the JSONObject.toString() method. Then set it to the `Bundle` object. For example:

```
   Bundle args=new Bundle();
   String userProfileString=userProfileJsonObject.toString();
   args.putString("userProfileString", userProfileString);
   fragmentUserProfile.setArguments(args);
```

Then in the destination fragment, inside the onCreateView method you can extract the String and reconvert it to the JSONObject.

```
String userProfileString=getArguments().getString("userProfileString");
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(userProfileString);
```

Hope this helps.