# How to send associative arrays from one fragment to another?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a `"MainActivity"` containing a fragment `"fragment1`", this fragment shows a loader until data is fetched using `Volley library`. After this fragment1 gets the `JSONResponse`, it has to pass the data to the second fragment `fragment2`. My data from JSON are as follows:

```
{ "city": ["Moscow", "Istanbul"],
 "Moscow":["Moscow Kremlin", "Red Square", "Gorky Park", "Saint Pittsburgh"],
"Istanbul":["Taksim Square", "Hagia Sophia", "Grand Bazaar", "Spice Bazaar"]}
```

The problem here is that the number of cities and places are not fixed. Information keeps adding up. I've completed the data retrieval process on `fragment1` but I'm unsure how to send it to the second fragment are retrieve the information there. Do I use `Bundle` or the `onFragmentInteractionListener`? And since there are no associative arrays in `Java`, how to I accomplish this?

Comment: Use interface concept.

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments

Comment: Yeah.. and what about associative arrays..?

Comment: Either fragment can parse the JSON string with an appropriate library.

Answer (score 1):

From below i will show you how to save and get values,

```
           Gson gson = new Gson();
           Example profile = new Example();
           Type listType = new TypeToken<Example>() {
                }.getType(); 
           profile = gson.fromJson(yourjson, listType);
           List<String> city = profile.getCity();
```

Example Class :

```
        package com.example;

    import java.util.List;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Example {

    @SerializedName("city")
    @Expose
    private List<String> city = null;
    @SerializedName("Moscow")
    @Expose
    private List<String> moscow = null;
    @SerializedName("Istanbul")
    @Expose
    private List<String> istanbul = null;

    public List<String> getCity() {
    return city;
    }

    public void setCity(List<String> city) {
    this.city = city;
    }

    public List<String> getMoscow() {
    return moscow;
    }

    public void setMoscow(List<String> moscow) {
    this.moscow = moscow;
    }

    public List<String> getIstanbul() {
    return istanbul;
    }

    public void setIstanbul(List<String> istanbul) {
    this.istanbul = istanbul;
    }

}
```

Comment: I considered it before asking this question. But, if you look at my data structure, the array is of "one to many" type and I think Map doesn't allow you to do that.

Comment: @AshishNeupane see the updated code.

Comment: You got a idea @AshishNeupane

Comment: As I already mentioned, the problem here is that the number of cities and places are not fixed. What if there's a new city `NewDelhi`? Then, I'd have to go to the source code and add that function `setDelhi()` and `getDelhi()`.

Comment: Then use json as string and pass to fragment and convert there and get what you want. And also refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371630/what-is-best-way-to-pass-json-data-one-fragment-to-another-fragment